# Maximum value of $\,{f(x) = \min (3x + 2, 5x + 1)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $f(x) = \min (3x + 2, 5x + 1)$, what is the maximum possible value of $f(x)$?

Both $3x+2$ and $5x+1$ are increasing functions and irrespective of which expression $f(x)$ takes, one thing is certain that $f(x)$ will also increase. Thus, $f(x)$ will have the maximum value at the highest value of $x$. Why is the answer shown as $\frac{7}{2}$ in my book?

Comment: Thats why you should specify a domain !

Comment: As $x \to \infty, f(x) \to \infty$. Your function is unbounded on $\mathbb{R}$. If your book has the answer $\frac{7}{2}$, the function must have also had a specified domain. What is this domain?

Comment: $\frac{7}{2}$ is the value of $f(0.5)$. That's the $y$ value of the point where the lines $y=3x+2$ and $5x+1$ cross

Comment: If the 3 were negative, then the maximum would indeed be at the intersection of the lines.  Perhaps the book's author had a brain fade.

Comment: No other information regarding domain is given in the question.

Comment: it is $$\cases{5\,x+1&$x\leq 1/2$\cr 3\,x+2&$1/2<x$\cr}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use from this fact that when $a,b$ are to real number, $min\{a,b\}=\frac{|a+b|-|a-b|}{2}$. So your function $f$, can be wrote as:

$$f(x)=\frac{|8x+3|-|2x-1|}{2}$$

And on the domain of $f$, find it's maximum.